# Is there an inverse of msync?

Tags: mmap

If you mmap a file, it creates a virtual mapping of some range of memory. Then  when you try to access that range of virtual address, it copies over the data from the region you are mapping to so you have the data.

Msync is supposed to synchronize any changes you made to the virtual range and copy those changes back to the memory you mapped to.

Is there a way to do the reverse of this? That is, to remap a virtual space to the same memory range, so that any changes made to the physical memory since the first time you used mmap are reflected in your virtual mapping?

The direct way to do this would be just to unmap and do mmap again, but I want to know if there is a more efficient method of doing this.

This is assuming that I am just using mmap to read from physical memory, not making any changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reverse operation as all the changes into underlying file are immediately available in the mapped memory - they share the same memory. The same for other mappings of the same file - they refer to the same physical memory so any change is immediately available in all other processes for all mappings of the same area.

Note that by file I mean any type of file, including physical devices, regular files, etc.

Comment: I had read at some point that  the mmap copies data over into a user space accessible area, and if it already has the data available, it will just use that rather than copying again. So does this mean that the OS knows to recopy data if it gets changed?

Comment: @GraigNelson : it doesn't copy, it maps. So there is single place in RAM where the data is stored and it's mapped to many places in virtual address space of many processes. They still point to the same physical location though so any update is immediately available to all others that have mapped the same area. Note: it doesn't have to be RAM, it can be file (which is then mapped via cache/buffer), it can be device like GPU, network card etc.